# Testing Passport Twitter Strategy

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-twitter

I'm looking for a simple way to simulate logging in with Twitter via Passport and testing some API calls to twitter with the login information.

Is this possible? Is there an easy way?

Any help is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't about easy but you can simulate the login using http://phantomjs.org/.
Here are some node modules which integerate phantomjs
https://github.com/baudehlo/node-phantom-simple
https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node

Hope this helps you.